# How to use the RabbitMQ producer and consumer in java spring micro services?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, microservices

I have some idea about message queue using RabbitMQ as a message broker. Now, i would like to implement this concept in my project. Currently, i am using spring micro-services and i need to integrate the RabbitMQ on this project.

Here, i could understand about publisher and subscriber workflow using rabbitMQ. Now, i am slightly confused about how to segregate the producer and consumer part in spring micro services.

Let's say, i have the two micro-services running. Now, i would like to invoke based corresponding micro-services by passing the message to queue.

If i am wrong please correct me and thoughts would be helpful for me to implement.

Can anyone provide me the samples using spring MVC with RabbitMQ. I googled out but i couldn't find helpful answers.

TIA...,

Comment: If you have time, Camel could help you.. If not - just use one MQ Connection Config for two of your instances and so on.

Comment: @Constantine Novykov Actually, i planned to use RabbitMQ and there will be MQ connection config. My doubt is how to use the producer and consumer in spring projects using MQ publish/subscribe pattern

Comment: Can you explain this line i am sorry i could not get your real question "Let's say, i have the two micro-services running. Now, i would like to invoke based corresponding micro-services by passing the message to queue". is this what you are looking below ? As far as i know messages on Queues can contain header information which can be helpful to identify or perform some kind of conditional logic on the message before processing it